# System include not completely consistent across distributions

Tags: c++, linux

### Short question

How should I deal with needing different includes on different distributions?

### More details

In some C++ code, I am including ioctl like this:

```
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```

And from that I use different things, including `TCSETS2`. Following the includes of `sys/ioctl.h` on Arch Linux, I found that `TCSETS2` is defined in `asm-generic/ioctls.h`. So far so good.

Now, when building on Alpine Linux, it complains about `TCSETS2`:

> error: 'TCSETS2' was not declared in this scope

Looking at the includes again, `TCSETS2` is also defined in `asm-generic/ioctls.h`. However, this time `sys/ioctl.h` does not end up including `generic/ioctls.h`.

How should I deal with that? Should I include both, hoping that it does not break the compilation on some distributions? Something like below?

```
#include <asm-generic/ioctls.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
```

Or is it bad practice?

Comment: I think the answer revolves around what are you doing with TCSETS2 because looking around it seems that it's an implementation specific thing that you use at your own risk

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html  TCSETS is the only thing mentioned

Comment: That is a very good point, I don't know why TCSETS2 is used (did I say it was only my code? :D). I will try to replace it by TCSETS and see what happens!

Comment: You were apparently right. Now using TCSETS. Could you write this as an answer, for the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCSETS2 is undocumented [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/tty_ioctl.4.html) 
suggesting that it's an implementation specific feature.  From the comments, switching to TCSETS which is in the documentation resolved the issue.